# angularJS how to dynamically bind input type date max/min value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to dynamically bind input field of date type with maximum date value in AngularJS? There are no `ng-max`, `ng-min` directives provided by AngularJS.

Comment: I want to set max date value 18 years less than current date on form loading event. Current date is fetched from server. Then max date is calculate in the controller. But I cannot bind max date value to the input element. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please check my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z07317wv/2/). Just bind your `$scope` vars directly into the tag attributes. I used [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for date handling.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="date" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" />
</div>
```

#### AngularJS App

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    //init dates
    var minDate = new moment();
    var maxDate = new moment().add(18, 'years'); 

    $scope.min = minDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    $scope.max = maxDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});
```

Comment: liked it, is it possible only with angular?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Sorry, what? I dont understand you.

Comment: without using moment.js how can I do it, if I want it only with angular?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal You can use `date`.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp